# Can Geometry vertex data be shared across three.js Ribbons?

Tags: three.js, vertexdata

I have a large set of vertices generated by interpolation of heart contours extracted from cardiac MRI slices which form a generally cylindrical shape.  In the current (C++) visualization, the vertex data is held in a single array and each lateral strip in the model is rendered as a triangle strip.

I am wondering if there is a way to share Geometry vertex data across multiple Ribbons and avoid having to create separate Geometry objects for each strip (thereby duplicating vertex data).